# regex for two positive integers separated by an underscore

Tags: regex

I need a Regex to match a string that must contains two positive integers separated by an undescore.

Examples:

12345_678 is Good
12345-678 is Bad
12345_678a is Bad

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? SO is not a site where you just come and ask other people to do stuff for you. You can learn about regular expressions here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^[0-9]+_[0-9]+$` will do it.

**Explanation**

- `^` the start of the string
- `[0-9]+` one or more digits
- `_` an underscore
- `[0-9]+` one or more digits
- `$` the end of the string

Comment: It would match `12345_678a` as well. You need to anchor the expression.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks - answer updated to use `^` and `$`