# IIS Rewrite Regex for two integers either side of string

Tags: regex, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

Big fan of the IIS 7.5 Rewrite module, I use it a lot, but can't figure out the regex for this.

I want **mysite.co.uk/1234-vs-4321/** to rewrite back to ASP as **mysite.co.uk/?prod1=1234&prod2=4321**

It needs to get the integers either side of **-vs-**

At the moment, 1234-vs-4321 as a whole is obviously being treated as prod1 because nothing's picking the string apart.

I have tried variations of:

```
^(\d+).*?(\d+)?$ 

^[0-9]+\-vs-[0-9]+$
```

(second example modified from SO answer [regex for two positive integers separated by an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436258/regex-for-two-positive-integers-separated-by-an-underscore) )

Here is the rule structure of the rewrite rule I'm working with:

```
<rule name="CompareProductsRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(\d+).*?(\d+)?$" />
     <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="?prod1={R:1}&amp;prod2={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Any help very gratefully received. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain this isn't the 'correct' way to do it because it's not limited to finding just the integers, but this seems to work the way I want:

```
^([^/]+)-vs-([^/]+)/?$
```

Thanks for looking.