# Validation for numbers and special character '_'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having a text box to enter value for session creation. I need to make restrictions for not allowing any kind of alphabets and special characters. As I need to enter value such as '2016_2017' and not anything else apart from this.

How can I validate for alphabets and any other special characters. Please Help.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [regex for two positive integers separated by an underscore](//stackoverflow.com/q/15436258)

Comment: code please....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex for two positive integers separated by an underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436258/regex-for-two-positive-integers-separated-by-an-underscore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the below code

```
$name = "2016_2017";
if(preg_match("/(\d+)_(\d+)$/",$name)){
    echo "Matched";
}
else{
    echo "Not matched";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check this link, here is your solution

```
<form action="">
Country code: <input type="text" name="country_code" 
pattern="[0-9]+_[0-9]+" title="enter valid code">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shailesh_cool8/2xLubp4o/